# Routing over openvpn

Tags: routing, openvpn

```
ip route list

default via 172.20.10.1 dev eth0
10.22.0.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.22.0.254
172.20.10.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.20.10.4
172.22.1.0/24 via 10.22.0.1 dev tun0
172.22.2.0/24 via 10.22.0.2 dev tun0
172.22.3.0/24 via 10.22.0.3 dev tun0
```

172.20.x.x are Azure VMs.
172.22.x.x are remote clients connected over openvpn.  VPN is 10.22.0.x

I can get from 172.22.0.0/16 to 172.20.11.5  (using nc and ping)
I cannot get back from 172.20.11.5 to 172.22.0.0/16 (neither nc or ping).

What am I missing?